# Update VSIX Extension Without Bumping Version

Tags: visual-studio-extensions, vsix, vsixmanifest

I'm developing a VSIX extension, and I'd like to make some changes and test them in the non-experimental instance without bumping the extension version.  When I install it the first time, it allows me to choose the instance to install to, but when I double click it a second time, it doesn't indicate that it can be installed anywhere, presumably because the version number hasn't been updated.  Is there any way to force it to install anyway?

Comment: If you want to update it, I think you have to change the version number:https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997169.aspx and https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2013/08/08/update-for-extension-authors-vsix-manifest-version-range-attribute/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uninstall and re-install in the instance if you do not want to bump the version number